I get an error when I want to save messages in a real-time chat application in Django
I don't get any error like this
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from .models import ChatRoom

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
async def connect(self):
self.room_name = self.scope\['url_route'\]\['kwargs'\]\['room_name'\]
self.room_group_name = f'chat\_{self.room_name}'

        await self.create_or_update_room(self.room_name)
        
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
    
        await self.accept()
    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Odayı terk et
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
    
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
    
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
      
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
    @database_sync_to_async
    def create_or_update_room(self, room_name):
            room, created = ChatRoom.objects.get_or_create(name=room_name)


(env) PS

C:\Users\Serkan\Desktop\stock_trackings\stock_tracking> daphne
-p 8000 stock_tracking.asgi:application "C:\Users\Serkan\Desktop\stock_trackings\env\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py",
line 260, in get_containing_app_config self.check_apps_ready() File
"C:\Users\Serkan\Desktop\stock_trackings\env\Lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py",
line 138, in check_apps_ready raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't
loaded yet.") django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't
loaded yet.

I get an error when I checked the settings, I checked the applications, and when I continue without saving the messages, it works without any problems.

Are you in an active virtual environment? Also can you show your INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'stock.apps.StockConfig',
'channels',
'django_tables2',
'stock',
'daphne',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
] @database_sync_to_async
def save_message(self, chat_room, user, message):
from stock.models import Message
When I introduce the model here, there is no problem.

Are you in an active virtual environment?

virtual environment enabled @database_sync_to_async
def save_message(self, chat_room, user, message):
from stock.models import Message
return Message.objects.create(
room=chat_room,
user=user,
content=message
)  from stock.models import Message It works like this, if I try to import it at the top it gives an error.
